# Defining indices for row sequences more succintly

Tags: r, dplyr, indices

I have a dataframe like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 50, replace = TRUE), 
                 B = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 50, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to filter the dataframe on two parameters: (i) the *target* rows that match a certain criterion and (ii) a certain number of rows that precede the target rows. Specifically, I want to filter rows where `A == "A" & B == "A"` as well as the **five** rows preceding the target row. I can do this with a two-step operation: first by defining a function, and second by using the function as input for `slice`:

```
Sequ <- function(col1, col2) {
  # get row indices of target row with function `which`
  inds <- which(col1 == "A" & col2 == "A") 
  # sort row indices of the rows before target row AND target row itself
  sort(unique(c(inds-5, inds-4, inds-3,inds-2, inds-1, inds)))
}

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  slice(Sequ(col1 = A, col2 = B))
   A B
1  D C
2  D B
3  C B
4  C D
5  B B
6  A A
7  E B
8  E D
9  D C
10 D D
11 A A
12 C C
13 D E
14 B E
15 B E
16 B A
17 A A
18 C D
19 C B
20 B D
21 A B
22 A A
```

But surely there must be a more efficient replacement for this part: `sort(unique(c(inds-5, inds-4, inds-3,inds-2, inds-1, inds)))`. In case I want to filter not just the preceding *5* but, say, *10* or *100* rows this way of defining each index individually becomes quickly impractical. How can this part be coded more economically?

Comment: So, to be clear, which of the two applies? Is it that (1) you want to filter your dataset to include those rows matching the criterion (`A == "A" & B == "A"`), and then include also the 5 rows immediately proceeding each such row.  Or (2) you want to filter your dataset to include only those rows that both (a) match the criterion and also (b) are preceded by 5 rows that also match the criterion?

Comment: Just option (1) ...

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!  Presumably, you don't want duplicates if the 5 preceding rows for one match overlap with the 5 preceding rows for another match.

Comment: Given `n <- 5`, you could use `data.table` for a rolling join, all in a single line: `setkey(df[, row := .I], row)[A == "A" & B == "B"][setkey(df[, row := .I], row), roll = -n, nomatch = 0]`.  The resulting fields need to be cleaned up, but the data in `i.A` | `i.B` | ... should be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Define bothA which takes a matrix and returns TRUE if any row is all A's.  Then use rollapply to apply it as a moving window.

```
library(zoo)

bothA <- function(x) any(rowSums(rbind(x) == "A") == 2)
ok <- rollapply(df, 6, bothA, align = "left", partial = TRUE, by.column = FALSE)
df[ok, ]
```

**2)** or in a pipe

```
df %>% 
  filter(rollapply(., 6, bothA, align = "left", partial = TRUE, by.column = FALSE))
```

**3)** This also works:

```
ok <- rollapply(rowSums(df == "A") == 2, 6, any, align = "left", partial = TRUE)
df[ok, ]
```

Comment: Nice, and thanks. Problem is that the solutions relies a lot on the merely illustrative condition that `A == "A" & B == "A"`. In the actual data, the conditions can be much more varied and complex. The point of the question is how to code the index sequence more efficiently.

Comment: Not so. It is perfectly general.  bothA can be replaced with an arbitrary function.

Comment: Ok, I get that. (That's why I've upvoted the answer.) So assuming I keep my function called `Sequ`, how could I use `rollaplly` with it?

Comment: I think much of the problem is that Sequ is not a ideal.  You want to generate a true or false for  each row, not a bunch of indices which are problematic to deal with.  Use bothA instead or replace it with something else but keeping the same philosoophy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution that can be directly used in a pipe, with no need for `filter`.

```
Sequ <- function(x, col1, col2, value = "A"){
  x %>%
    mutate(grp = lag(cumsum({{col1}} == value & {{col2}} == value), default = 0)) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    slice_tail(n = 5) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
}

df %>% Sequ(A, B)
## A tibble: 23 x 2
#   A     B    
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 B     D    
# 2 C     C    
# 3 E     A    
# 4 D     B    
# 5 A     A    
# 6 C     D    
# 7 E     E    
# 8 C     E    
# 9 C     C    
#10 A     A    
## … with 13 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
df %>%
 filter(!row_number() %in% unlist(map(which(A == "A" & B == "A"), ~ (.x-5):.x)))
```